# Why does it say "1 questions" rather than "1 question" with new activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Why does the notification at top about number of questions with new activity says "1 questions" rather than grammatically correct "1 question"?

[image]

Is this error uniform among all SE sites? I waited for sometime to see what happens at https://ell.stackexchange.com/. Looks like I have wait a bit more to find out.

**UPDATE**

Yes, this happens at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) as well.

[image]

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @MarcGravell I always welcome a guest, however unwelcome one may be. :-)

Comment: Related: [“1 times” is incorrect, every time](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3347/5764)

Comment: Should be working correctly now: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/1-new-answers-pluralization-bug